# sh: ./filebeat: not found in Docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, alpine-linux, filebeat, s6

Im trying to run filebeat in a docker container with the s6 overlay.
When s6 executes or when i manually execute the filebeat binary i get `sh: ./filebeat: not found`
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.15

ENV AM_I_IN_A_DOCKER_CONTAINER Yes

COPY root/ /
ADD https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v1.21.8.0/s6-overlay-amd64.tar.gz /tmp/
ADD https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-8.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz /tmp/
ADD requirements.txt /etc/services.d/01_instabot/requirements.txt
ADD src/ /etc/services.d/01_instabot/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install.sh
RUN /usr/local/bin/install.sh

#ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```

This is my install.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Unpacking s6 overlay"
gunzip -c /tmp/s6-overlay-amd64.tar.gz | tar -xf - -C /

echo "Creating user"
adduser -D -u 2000 -s /sbin/nologin -D -H botuser
adduser -D -u 2001 -s /sbin/nologin -D -H filebeatuser

echo "Set time"
ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/"$TZ" /etc/localtime && echo "$TZ" > /etc/timezone
apk add --no-cache tzdata

echo "Install filebeat"
gunzip -c /tmp/filebeat-8.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz | \
  tar -xf - -C /etc/services.d/00_filebeat/ --strip-components=1
mv /etc/services.d/00_filebeat/my_filebeat.yml /etc/services.d/00_filebeat/filebeat.yml

echo "Install app dependencies"
apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /etc/services.d/01_instabot/requirements.txt
mv /etc/services.d/01_instabot/settings_docker.py /etc/services.d/01_instabot/settings.py

echo "Cleanup"
rm -rf /tmp/*
```

If i take a look inside the docker container with the `docker run` command i see the binary present.

```
/etc/services.d/00_filebeat # ls
LICENSE.txt             README.md               filebeat                filebeat.yml            module                  run
NOTICE.txt              fields.yml              filebeat.reference.yml  kibana                  modules.d
```

But when i execute it using `./filebeat` i get the not found error.

```
/etc/services.d/00_filebeat # ./filebeat
sh: ./filebeat: not found
```

Why is this? And how do i fix it? Is it because of busybox or something?

Comment: Shared-library dependencies from the Alpine image are definitely a potential issue.  Does it work if you change the base to `FROM ubuntu:20.04`?  What does `ldd filbeat` tell you?

Comment: @DavidMaze It worked fine in an Ubuntu image. While looking at the https://github.com/easonlau02/filebeat-alpine/blob/master/6.1.1/Dockerfile container i noticed libc6-compat also being installed. Installing this in my alpine container fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libc6-compat was missing from my alpine image.